# Chat server writing to closed sockets

Tags: java, sockets

Essentially I have a server class and a client class, the client creates a socket and sends whatever you type into the server, which gets written to the output streams of a vector of sockets from all the existing clients. It works well except when you close a chat client, after which the next message sent gives the following exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
```

I think what's happening is that the socket closed by the client is either not closing the socket in the server's vector of sockets, or that even when it's closed, it remains in the vector and then tries to write to a closed socket. Does this sound like what might be happening? I don't understand exactly what the socket.close() method does regarding the socket it's connected to.

Answer (score 1):

You close the socket on the client side, but on the server side it is not closed and this is why you get this exception.

In a graceful close you should send a CLOSE message from your client which will close the socket on the server side.

If a socket on the client was closed then you must handle your exception on the server side e.g. by removing it from your vector of sockets.

Comment: He doesn't need a CLOSE message, and nothing the client can do will magically close the socket at the server. Only the server can do that. He just has to write a close() at both ends.

Answer (score 0):

If the client closes his socket you will read EOS at the server (`read()` returns -1, `readLine()` returns `null`,`readXXX()` throws `EOFException` for any other X), or get an `IOException: connection reset by peer` when writing, probably not on the first write. If either of these things happens you must close the socket in the server and forget about that client in all ways.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's like both sides of connection are holding together by hands, and if you split them they always will feel it. Check if socket is closed before sending and catch exceptions to solve this problem.

Comment: Checking whether the socket is closed won't tell him whether the connection is closed by the other end.